# How to use insert query with select sub query and where clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this but its went wrong

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `shopping_cart`  
(userid`,`product_id`,`pr_name`, `pr_price`)  
VALUES('$us_id','$pr_id','$pname','$prprice')  
WHERE(SELECT `product_id` FROM `product_tb_men`  
JOIN `shopping_cart` ON product_tb_men.pr_id= shopping_cart.product_id  
WHERE product_tb_men.pr_id=$pr_id)";
```

Comment: update is used with WHERE clause not insert

Comment: You can't do INSERT with WHERE clause

Comment: can u please describe me how ? @raveenanigam

Comment: If you are using WHERE clause, it means you already have that row in the table. If it is already present, then why use INSERT, use UPDATE query

Comment: Just read both the article : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Proper DDLs and a before and after would probably help,

Comment: Can you describe your problem? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I agree, please specify what you want to do for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @Strawberry i have multiple products in my age i want to get the ID of that product which has been clicked by the user so with the help of ID i can UPDATE data by where clause

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Comment: You can do it but I'm not clear about which column will get inserted into which column and from which table. Please clear me this will a bit explanation of your need..

Comment: @Strawberry simply i need to UPADTE data with where clause but from a php variable $ID

Comment: @Strawberry its just inserting same id as i have multiple products see the image, In this image i've multiple products snag.gy/KBgVj.jpg when i clicked in any of them its inserting the first one product's id see here snag.gy/royGc.jpg

Comment: You need to amend your question accordingly. The comments section is not the right place for this information

Answer (score 0):

May be You need this :

```
UPDATE `shopping_cart` 
SET userid = '$us_id',
  `product_id` = '$pr_id',
  `pr_name` = '$pname', 
  `pr_price` = '$prprice'
WHERE <field_name_for_id> IN (SELECT `product_id` FROM `product_tb_men`  
 JOIN `shopping_cart` ON product_tb_men.pr_id= shopping_cart.product_id  
 WHERE product_tb_men.pr_id='$pr_id')
```

Comment: It doesn't work it says syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`pr_price` = 20 WHERE (SELECT * FROM `product_tb_men` JOIN `shopping_cart' at line 4

Comment: I've updated the answer as per the syntax for select in where clause.

Comment: The syntax error is because you need to quote your update values.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE clause cannot used with INSERT.
The subquery below of SELECT i have kept as it is what u have given. The changes is in the remaining main query

```
UPDATE `shopping_cart` 
    SET `userid` = '$us_id', 
      `product_id` = '$pr_id', 
      `pr_name` = '$pname', 
      `pr_price` = '$prprice'
    WHERE `product_id` in (SELECT `product_id` FROM `product_tb_men`  
     JOIN `shopping_cart` ON product_tb_men.pr_id= shopping_cart.product_id  
     WHERE product_tb_men.pr_id=$pr_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
"INSERT INTO `shopping_cart` (`userid`,`product_id`,`pr_name`, `pr_price`)  
SELECT '$us_id', '$pr_id','$pname','$prprice' FROM `product_tb_men` 
JOIN `shopping_cart` ON product_tb_men.pr_id= shopping_cart.product_id  
WHERE product_tb_men.pr_id= $pr_id"
```

Comment: Its works good but i need something different its just inserting same id as i have multiple products see the image, In this image i've multiple products http://snag.gy/KBgVj.jpg when i clicked in any of them its inserting the first  one product's id see here http://snag.gy/royGc.jpg

Comment: Okay, if you click any one of them then what do you want? Do you want to insert one record?

Comment: LIMIT 1 at the end of the query will do it for now. But it would be nice if you could share the product_tb_men as well.